# Как правильно отсортировать данную строку?

Tags: python, строки, сортировка

У меня имеется строка:

```
"Ваня 20 Вася 10"
```

Мне из этого нужно отсортировать так, чтобы получить:

```
"Вася 10 Ваня 20"
```

Но! если числа одинаковый необходимо сортировать по буквам:
было
    Саша 15 Дима 15
стало

```
"Дима 15 Саша 15"
```

(потому что буква Д в алфавите стоит первее)
Таких имен и цифр в строку может быть хоть 1, хоть 20

Comment: string [] str = new string[] {"Вася" , "10", "Ваня", "10"}; а дальше в цикле `str[i][0] >str[i+1][0]` то меняем местами элементы.

Comment: Какой-то странный у вас питон

Comment: я написал алгоритм, а реализация на других языках это ваше решение...

Comment: Алгоритм - это когда объясняется словами, или иным способом, не привязанным к синтаксическим конструкциям конкретного ЯП. Кроме того, у вас и алгоритм неправильный. Во-первых, у вас числа будут сортироваться лексиграфически, а не как числа. Во-вторых, "в цикле меняем местами" - это явно не является корректным описанием сортировки.

Comment: Что самое комичное, Вы же даже не указали ЯП...

Comment: Метод пузырька) Пару условий на Число или Буква в строке

Comment: .NET платформа, язык c#, IDE VS, версия фрейма 4

Comment: Такс, иду учить C# , нужно понять ответ на вопрос написаный по питону. Потом иду учить питон, так как кажется что вопрос схож на ту проблему которая у меня в ждаве...

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться стандартной сортировкой ([Timsort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), `O(N*logN)`). Если передать ей кортеж, то сортировка будет производиться сначала по-первому элементу, затем по-второму и т. д.

То есть, нужно преобразовать строку к списку кортежей вида:

```py
[('20', 'Ваня'), ('10', 'Вася'), ('15', 'Саша'), ('15', 'Дима')]
```

а затем отсортировать и преобразовать обратно в строку.

***Пример:***

```py
def main():
    text = 'Ваня 20 Вася 10 Саша 15 Дима 15'

    li = text.split()
    users = sorted((int(li[i+1]), li[i]) for i in range(0, len(li), 2))

    result = ' '.join(' '.join((name, str(num))) for num, name in users)
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
Вася 10 Дима 15 Саша 15 Ваня 20
```

Comment: Хорошо, я разобрался, теперь не подскажешь, пожалуйста, как превратить из строки такой список кортежей? а то я не понял как

Comment: @АхмедЦороев Сначала я разделяю строку по пробелам. Затем генерирую диапазон от `0` до длины списка через `2`. И наконец составляю список кортежей (с помощью спискового включения), итерируясь по диапазону (где `li[i]` — имя, `li[i+1]` — число). В коде я делаю это на строке 5 (`users = ...`), попутно сортируя список.